# %2F encoding added at end of url, laravel, nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-4

Firstly, I use nginx for hosting. My question:

When using Redirect::intended I get the url directory after the correct url. Eg. I get

```
mydomain.com/admin/dashboard?q=%2Fadmin%2Fdashboard
```

instead of

```
mydomain.com/admin/dashboard
```

Edit: the above problem was caused by having redirect::intended(route('dashboard')) instead of redirect::intended('dashboard'). I still don't know what causes the below problem.

How do i get rid of the encoding at the end of my url?

Also related, in my log I keep on getting:

> Error for URL: mydomin.com/public/images/favIcon.png?q=%2Fpublic%2Fimages%2FfavIcon.png
>
> [2015-04-21 16:26:35] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in stuff/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:148
>       Stack trace: ...

I have a favicon in public/images/favIcon.png btw. Actually when I test my site I don't seem to trigger this error. But It does appear in my log files after about an hour or so. I presume its a user with some different browser that causes it.

Comment: Can you post the code for your dashboard route and the code your using the `Redirect::intended()` in?

Comment: Steve, I realised the mistake I made, I had redirect::intended(route('dashboard'))

I still have the favicon with encoded slashes problem in my log file tho.

Comment: Ok great, however you'll need to post your routes for me to look deeper into that issue though.